# Issue with Google Apps Script code copy-paste from Gsheet file

Tags: database, google-apps-script, google-sheets, bigdata, copy-paste

I've created a code to copy-paste the values from the most recent uploaded Gsheet file to another. The code is supposed to copy-paste only values that fulfil a cell condition.

The problem is, this code takes to long to run and doesn't finish to copy all values before having a run-time error.

The file has about 300.000 cells and the final amounts to be pasted on the 2nd file have about 90.000 cells.

Does anyone have a recommendation on how to proceed?

Thank you so much for your kind support.

```
 function Master_Run_DB() {
 Copy_EUDB();
 
}

function Copy_EUDB() {          
    var myLink = extractLink_EUDB();
    sendData_EUDB(myLink);            
}

function extractLink_EUDB() {
    var newData = new Date().toLocaleString();
    var drive = DriveApp.getFolderById("link to file");
    var file = drive.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
    var link = file.next().getUrl();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 
    return link
 
}

function sendData_EUDB(link) {
 var mainSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("link to file");
 var lastRow = mainSS.getSheetByName("Database").getLastRow();
  mainSS.getSheetByName("Database").getRange("A2" + ":R" + lastRow).clearContent();
 var baseSS = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(link);
 Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl());
 var lRow = baseSS.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getLastRow();

  
 for (var i = 2; i <= lRow; i++) {
   var cell = baseSS.getRange("G" + i);
   var val = cell.getValue();
   if (val == "EU") {
     
     var sourceData = baseSS.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("A" + i + ":R" + i).getValues();
     var to         = mainSS.getSheetByName("Database").getRange("A" + i + ":R" + i).setValues(sourceData);
     
   }
 }  
};
```

Hello again,

Now that the new code is working, I was trying to add an IF AND clause to the copy-paste. The objective would be to copy only values that fulfil the following condition:

Column 7 = "EU"
Column 11 <> "CCCC"

But I'm getting a Syntax Error. Any advice?

Thank you in advance for your kind support

```
function Master_Run_EU() {
  var drive = DriveApp.getFolderById("link to file");
  var file = drive.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  var link = file.next().getUrl();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("link to file");
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Database');
  sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow(),22).clearContent();
  var dbss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(link);
  const dbsh=dbss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var oA=[];
  var vs=dbsh.getRange(2,1,dbsh.getLastRow()-1,22).getValues();
  vs.forEach(function(r,i){
    if(r[7]=="EU" && r[11]<>"CCCC") {
      oA.push(r);
    }
  });
  sh.getRange(2,1,oA.length,oA[0].length).setValues(oA);
}
```

Comment: What's the syntax error?

Comment: One thing I would suggest, ask the next question in a new posting.  When I read thru this, it seems like 1 question was asked and answered, then you post a follow-up question in the same posting.

Comment: Hello lincolnadym. Yes, I understand your recommendation and will do so in future postings. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function Master_Run_DB() {
  var drive = DriveApp.getFolderById("1ViOyzIkGOI6G6SMrtmPv4vjL-2-2duHC");
  var file = drive.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  var link = file.next().getUrl();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("13CchyoqiWyvGTnYuG5TWA4cggBS-FsoDkW8XGesDkiY");
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Database');
  sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow(),18).clearContent();
  var dbss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(link);
  const dbsh=dbss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var vs=dbsh.getRange(2,1,dbsh.getLastRow()-1,18).getValues();
  vs.forEach(function(r,i){
    if(r[6]=="EU") {
      sh.getRange(i+2,1,1,18).setValues([r]);
    }
  });
}
```

It would be faster to do it this way:

```
function Master_Run_DB() {
  var drive = DriveApp.getFolderById("1ViOyzIkGOI6G6SMrtmPv4vjL-2-2duHC");
  var file = drive.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  var link = file.next().getUrl();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("13CchyoqiWyvGTnYuG5TWA4cggBS-FsoDkW8XGesDkiY");
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Database');
  sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow(),18).clearContent();
  var dbss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(link);
  const dbsh=dbss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var oA=[];
  var vs=dbsh.getRange(2,1,dbsh.getLastRow()-1,18).getValues();
  vs.forEach(function(r,i){
    if(r[6]=="EU") {
      oA.push(r);
    }
  });
  sh.getRange(2,1,oA.length,oA[0].length).setValues(oA);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It worked perfectly!

Comment: One additional remark. When I try to adapt this code to a similar file that has 22 columns I get an error linked to the "length" property. Anyone can help me understand why? Thank you.

Comment: It worked already. Thank you so much for your help with this issue!